# The name of the city on a postal cancel

Tags: translation, names

Hi can someone help me with translation of the city (town) name on this postal cancel - on attached photo. Does it start with Chong-? Thank you. Tomaz

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's probably 북청 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pukchong_County) based on your second picture. It's not a city (시) and it's currently in North Korea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `북청`[book-cheong]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pukchong_County

> 북 청
>
> 58.12.28
>
> ★

> 함남도 북청군 농업 전문학교 원예과 (송길녀)